# Sending an image to WCF from silverlight as a byte[] failes when exceding 48765 bytes

Tags: silverlight, wcf, soap

I am trying to send an image from a silverlight client to a WCF service.

I have the following classes to send

```
namespace PhotoViewer.DataObjects.Requests
{
    public class SavePhotoRequest
    {
        public Photo Photo { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace PhotoViewer.DataObjects.Entitys
{
    public class Photo
    {
        public Photo() { }

        public Photo(int id, DateTime takeOn, Byte[] photoBinary)
        {
            _iD = id;
            _takenOn = takeOn;
            _photoBinary = photoBinary;
        }

        int _iD;
        DateTime _takenOn;
        Byte[] _photoBinary;

        public int ID { get { return _iD; } set { _iD = value; } }
        public DateTime TakeOn { get { return _takenOn; } set { _takenOn = value; } }
        public Byte[] PhotoBinary { get { return _photoBinary; } set { _photoBinary = value; } }
    }
}
```

I have tried to set everything to max in my config files as follows

**ServiceReference.ClientConfig**

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
           name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoService"
           closeTimeout="10:00:00"
           openTimeout="10:00:00"
           receiveTimeout="10:00:00"
           sendTimeout="10:00:00"
           maxBufferSize="2147483647"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"           
           textEncoding="utf-8" 
           transferMode="Buffered">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:52715/PhotoService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoService"
                contract="PhotoViewer.Model.ServiceContracts.IPhotoService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IPhotoService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PhotoViewer.Service.Implementations.PhotoService"
          behaviorConfiguration="PhotoDebugBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="PhotoViewer.Service.Interfaces.IPhotoService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPivotService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PhotoDebugBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
           name="BasicHttpBinding_IPivotService"
           closeTimeout="10:00:00"
           openTimeout="10:00:00"
           receiveTimeout="10:00:00"
           sendTimeout="10:00:00"
           maxBufferSize="2147483647"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
           textEncoding="utf-8" >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But it just won't work as soon as the array of Bytes exceeds 48765.  I get the following response from fiddler.

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server:
>   ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
>   Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 21:58:57 GMT
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   Cache-Control: private Content-Length:
>   0 Connection: Close

I have read many articles in which this seems to work with just increasing all the sizes in the config files, but I have put these all to maximum and just can't work out what I have missed.

**EDIT**

Here is PhotoService.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
                Debug="true" 
                Service="PhotoViewer.Service.Implementations.PhotoService" %>
```

and PhotoService.cs

```
namespace PhotoViewer.Service.Implementations
{
   public class PhotoService : IPhotoService
    {
        IUnityContainer container;

        public PhotoService()
        {
            SetUnityContainer();
        }

        public SavePhotoResult SavePhoto(SavePhotoRequest request)
        {
            var imageRepository = container.Resolve<IPhotoRepository>();

            imageRepository.SavePhoto(request.Photo);

            container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>().SubmitChanges();

            return new SavePhotoResult();
        }

        private void SetUnityContainer()
        {
            container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, DatabaseUnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IRepository<Photo>, Repository<Photo>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IPhotoRepository, PhotoRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `PhotoService.svc` and `PhotoService.svc.cs`?

Comment: Have you tried Streamed mode?

Comment: Well the thought did cross my mind, by I don't think you can set up the ClientConfig File to use transferMode="Streamed".. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: It seems that the mistake is here: <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>. I would increase this value too.

Comment: I've tried to read and display an image from the WCF Service with default settings, and it works. Maybe because of the fact that I deploy the service on the local IIS.

Comment: I modified the maxRequestLength

Comment: I modified the maxRequestLength to 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240000"/>
This will not let me send 1 more byte than I could before. And I think that that value is now more than 1GB, think it was at 10MB before.  The image I am trying to send is 500KB but like i say it will only let me send 48,765 Bytes of it.

I also changed the settings to debug against IIS and this hasn't helped either.  

How big was the image that you were displaying?  and what format was it in when you transfered it? Could you try sending it back from the silverlight to WCF, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Oh how embarassing, seems I was just being a total Numpty!

Somehow I ended up with a web.config file in the project that contained my service interfaces and implementations. I had been changing all the settings in this config file and not the config file that was being used in the asp.net hosting project.

As soon as I copied the settings from wrong config to correct config file it all worked !!
Yeah sometimes it's best not to burn the midnight oil